# Android Remote API calls. How to use JSON data to create new Class definition

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which makes remote API calls to fetch some data.
Remote server fetches data from DB table. I have java class which maps to table columns in both Android app and on Server which sends data.

```
DB TABLE: 
Item (
    item_id  bigint(20) 
    item_name varchar(20)
    price decimal(8,2)
);


//Item class
Class Item {
    private long itemId;
    private String itemName;
    private Float price;

    //Corresponding getters/setters
}
```

STEP1: Remote API convert "**Item**" Object to `JSON` and send it to android app
STEP2: Mobile app casts JSON to "**Item**" class using `JSONP`

PROBLEM:
Item table on server side is bound to change and over period of time we need to add new columns. Now If I add new columns in server side "STEP2" will break thus app crashes(because of new column). I need to modify apps Item class to accomodate new column so that it won't break. But, If I modify app, app crashed for users who haven't updated app (since they have old item table).

QUESTION:
Suppose, I can send table definition when app starts. What is best way to use this `JSON` Map to create new Item class out of it?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I rather removed all data from Item file and added only Map<String,Object> . This will solve all problems